# Opponent video is not displaying in Twilio Video

Tags: swift, twilio

I am using `TwilioVideo` for video calling. My problem is when I connect to a video room only voice is working. My code and issue as shown below.

[image]

Comment: please do not put code in form of an image into your question... noone will want to retype your code, just to answer you...

Answer (score 0):

It is a compilation error. It looks like the `addRenderer` method does not exist on the `subscribedVideoTrack`. I am not familiar with Swift but I think you should add the renderer on the `publication` object.